# 'String' does not contain a reference for 'Text'

Tags: asp.net

The .Text on add is giving the error, I believe I have the right assemblies in place.

```
StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    //extract the TextBox values
    string txt1 = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox1" + i.ToString())).Text;
    string txt2 = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox2" + i.ToString())).Text;
    string txt3 = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox3" + i.ToString())).Text;
    string txt4 = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox4" + i.ToString())).Text;
    string txt5 = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox5" + i.ToString())).Text;
    string txt6 = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox6" + i.ToString())).Text;
    string txt7 = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox7" + i.ToString())).Text;
    string txt8 = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox8" + i.ToString())).Text;
    string txt9 = ((TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox9" + i.ToString())).Text;

    sc.Add(txt1.Text, txt2.Text, txt3.Text, txt4.Text, txt5.Text, txt6.Text, txt7.Text, txt8.Text, txt9.Text);
}

    InsertRecords(sc);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically calling `string.Text` since the type of `txt1, txt2, etc` is string, hence the error. But note that you are already calling `.Text` on the `TextField` control so what you probably intend to do is:

```
sc.AddRange(new string[]{txt1, txt2, txt3, ...});
```